# Application remote demo streaming difficulties

Tags: streaming, remote-access, video-capture, remote-desktop

We developed an app on a proprietary OS and need to demo it to customers. The the app’s many dependencies makes on-site customer demos too expensive.

I’ve plugged a projector into the hdmi when the customers are at our offices, but since Covid that isn't an option.

We’ve tried pointing a webcam at the video but that looks fuzzy and distant. Is there a way to send HDMI output back into a desktop device for screen sharing?

Comment: is there something I can do to offer a reward for this one?  we're at our wit's end.

Comment: Hire a specialist nearby to fix the problem if you want to reward someone. I think this is mostly physical-based than software-based, right?

Comment: What sort of specialist could do this?  It seems like I need some hardware or software, not an expert.